# Knockout.js with REST services - combining parent / child data

Tags: rest, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm very new to Knockout but really loving it, certainly makes a massive difference compared to the old manual techniques!

I'm currently working on a single page application to display phone calls made from a users extension(s). I have created some REST services:

`GET /extensions` - returns a list of extension numbers that are available to the current user

`GET /calls/<extension>` - returns a list of calls made on the given extension

Inside my SPA I'd like to list out a table per extension showing the data about the phone calls, but not sure what angle to take in terms of my view model.

At the moment I'm thinking something like the following:

```
function extension(extn) {
    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(extn);
    model.calls = ko.observableArray(); // load calls in to here

    return model;
}

function CallsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.extnData = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("/extensions", null, function (data) {
        self.extnData($.map(data, extension));
    });
}
```

Where I load the extensions into the model initially, and then following that load the calls in to the extension objects. But I'm just winging it at this stage so unsure if this is ideal?

Are there any suggestions on how this should be approached, happy to take comments at any level, including the REST API itself (though I think that side of it is reasonable). Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interacting with REST services shouldn't really change the way your viewmodel code is structured. Hopefully you are isolating your data access away from your viewmodel code so that it doesn't matter how they are retrieved. You can do this in a lot of ways, but wrapping them in a `service` object is a pretty common one.

Not exactly sure if this is what you are after, since you don't give any hint at what the structure of your data is, I can't be sure. You are on the right path for sure, but I would do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LW333/1/):

```
var Call = function (data) {
    this.number = ko.observable(data.number);
    this.duration = ko.observable(data.duration);
};

var Extension = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id)
    self.calls = ko.observableArray();

    self.callsLoaded = ko.observable(false);
    self.loadCalls = function() {
        var calls = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataService.getCallsMock(self.id()), function (c) {
           return new Call(c); 
        });
        self.calls(calls);
        self.callsLoaded(true);
    };
};

var Viewmodel = function() {
    var self = this;

    var extensions = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataService.getExtensionsMock(), function(e) {
       return new Extension(e); 
    });
    self.extensions = ko.observableArray(extensions);
};
```

Obviously the mock ajax calls will be callback-based when you actually make them.

The idea here is that loading the extensions happens immediately, but the calls for each extension is done on demand. That's what it sounded like you meant, but it wasn't really clear.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for that and apologies for my vagueness in some aspects - was a bit of a mind dump before the end of the day. You've definitely pushed me in the right direction - really I was just confirming that I wasnt about to head off on some crazy tangent. Cheers!